# Can't pass function to set of HTML files in rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I have an `rvest` function that works:

```
tables <- lapply(paste0("http://www.derecho.uba.ar/institucional/docentes/prof_index.php?pagina=",1:26,"&criterio="), 
                      function(url){
                        read_html(url) %>% 
                          html_nodes("table") %>%
                            .[4] %>%
                            html_table(fill = TRUE)
                          
                      })
```

I am trying to replicate the same structure for a different function, to **scrape** a set of HTML files in my computer.

The code is the following:

```
tables <- lapply(paste0("/Users/ramiroalvarezugarte/Dropbox/Consultorias/20_CELE/2_osi_jueces/data/webpages/web",1:9,".html"), 
    function(url){
  
  expediente <- html_nodes(url, ".col-xs-10.col-sm-10.col-md-10.col-lg-10") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
  tbls <- html_nodes(url, "table")
  tbls_ls <- url %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="expediente:participantsTable"]') %>%
        html_table(fill = TRUE)
  tbls_ls <- as.data.frame(tbls_ls)

  is.na(tbls_ls) <- tbls_ls==''

  tbls_ls <- tbls_ls[rowSums(is.na(tbls_ls)) != ncol(tbls_ls), ]

  usual_words <- c("TIPO :", "NOMBRE :")

  tbls_ls$TIPO  =  removeWords(tbls_ls$TIPO,usual_words)     #Remove stopwords
  tbls_ls$NOMBRE  =  removeWords(tbls_ls$NOMBRE,usual_words)     #Remove stopwords

  tbls_ls <- as.data.frame(t(tbls_ls))

  tbls_ls2 <- tbls_ls %>%
    row_to_names(row_number = 1)

  tbls_ls2 <- tbls_ls2[1,]

  expediente <- as.data.frame(expediente)

  df2 <- data.frame(expediente=character(),
                 camara=character(), 
                 juzgado=character(),
                 estado=character(),
                 caratula=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

  df2 <- cbind(expediente[1,], expediente[2,], expediente[3,], expediente[4,], expediente[5,],tbls_ls2)

  names(df2)[1] <- 'expediente'
  names(df2)[2] <- 'camara'
  names(df2)[3] <- 'juzgado'
  names(df2)[4] <- 'estado'
  names(df2)[5] <- 'caratula'

  cols <- names(df2)

  cols

  inds1 <- which(cols == "LETRADO PATROCINANTE")
  inds2 <- which(cols == "LETRADO APODERADO")


  names(df2)[inds1] <- paste( cols[inds1], cols[inds1 - 1],sep = '_')
  names(df2)[inds2] <- paste( cols[inds2], cols[inds2 - 1],sep = '_')

  df2 <- clean_names(df2)

  return(df2)
})
```

I get, however, the following error:

```
 Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I have been stuck with this for almost two days. Any advice / help on what I am clearly doing wrong is really appreciated.

Comment: several times you try  html_nodes(url, "<css selector>")  when you need to e.g. read_html(url) %>% html_nodes('table') as html_nodes() is a method to call on the object returned by read_html(url)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I see that was a first of many mistakes. I will re-work the code and update the question.

Comment: This isn't a valid URL that you have shared. There is no webpage at http://www.derecho.uba.ar/institucional/docentes/prof_index.php?pagina=1&criterio= and it returns a 404.